# How can I remove empty directories in git-svn?

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

I have a specific problem I did not find a solution for, here or anywhere else. I have a Subversion repository and I am using git-svn to access it and work on it.

Some time ago, there were some empty directories in the Subversion repository (empty, only subfolders). Git does not track those. Then they were deleted from the Subversion repository. But I still have them even after running this command:

```
git svn rebase
```

And when I delete them by hand, they are recreated during the next command:

```
git svn rebase
```

How can I get rid of them?

I checked using pure Subversion and they are not in the repository.

Comment: Hmmm, that's odd. Git doesn't know about or track directories at all. Have you checked if there are any old invisible files in those directories which your boss might have missed when he deleted them? Try doing a `ls -la` in the directory to check for hidden files.

Comment: Midnight Commander does not hide stuff ;) The folders are empty. Can this be a bug? :/

Comment: I've had many (many) frustrations with Git, but I have yet to stumble upon a legit "bug." Most of my frustrations have turned out to be due to my lack of understanding. What happens if you do `git status` from the Git command-line; do the folders show up as being "untracked" by any chance? If you do `git ls-files directory_name --error-unmatch` on these directories; does it return `true` or `false`? Try re-cloning the repository (`git clone`) with Git to see if the folders are included with a fresh clone; maybe they're just hanging around from an older revision. I'm just guessing wildly here.

Comment: Also, check to bake sure that you're in the correct branch where these folders were deleted (`git branch`and look for the `*` next to the name). Could they have been removed in a different branch and not merged to your branch yet? (Again, this is very peculiar, since Git is blissfully unaware of any directories. Maybe it's because of some way `git-svn` handles directories that I'm unaware of).

Comment: 1) nope, git status does not show them at all, after all, they are empty, so git ignores them..
2) git ls-files directory_name --error-unmatch returns:
error: pathspec 'application' did not match any file(s) known to git.
Did you forget to 'git add'?
3) after doing frech git svn clone ... they are still there
4) yep, I am on right branch, it's fresh project so there's only trunk anyway

Comment: Hmmm. Okay, I've got this mulling in the back of my mind. Maybe something else will come to mind but, unfortunately, I don't have any other ideas at this moment.

Comment: Think I found the problem. Adding an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bit rough, but I have found that the following solves my problem:

```
rm .git/svn/refs/remotes/trunk/unhandled.log
git clean -df
```

Any subsequent

```
git svn rebase
```

will not recreate anything.

Since I don't know how to regenerate this file without re-cloning the repo, I suggest making a backup of it first. It is a text file, so I suppose you could also edit its content to remove the entries that end up creating

Comment: Don't delete stuff in `.git`.

Answer (score 16):

I think you'll find your answer in [this blog post](http://www.peterboling.com/2011/4/26/git-svn-fails-to-delete-directories).

> [...]
>
> Remove directories from the SVN tree if there are no files left
>   behind.  SVN can version empty directories, and they are not removed
>   by default if there are no files left in them.  git cannot version
>   empty directories.  Enabling this flag will make the commit to SVN act
>   like git. `config key: svn.rmdir`
>
> To fix the root of the problem set the git config globally:
>
> `git config --global svn.rmdir true`
>
> [...]

Comment: I found this when googling too, but it's not answer to my question. This is for situations when you delete folder and commiting it via git. My problem is that someone deleted directory via svn but I still have it in git repository (but they're empty) and when I delete them they are automatically recreated on next rebase.

Comment: I guess it's not really "the right thing to do," but maybe you could (using Git) add a dummy text files into the folders, `add` and `commit` them so that they are tracked and then delete (`git rm`) the files and commit the deletion. Then maybe you'd get rid of the folders, but it would dirty up your history a bit.

Comment: I can see where would boss send me with this approach :D

Comment: By the way, have you tried doing `git clean -fd`to remove all untracked files and directories? Maybe that'll work. **Warning:** Do not do this if you have any untracked files (new files) in your working tree that you actually want to keep, as they will also be deleted when you do this.

Comment: the actual command to modify config is `git config --global svn.rmdir true`

Comment: Link to blog post is dead.

Answer (score 4):

Tell `git svn` that it should not try to recreate empty directories:

```
git config svn-remote.svn automkdirs false
```

This is the relevant section of the man page:

> svn-remote.<name>.automkdirs
>
> Normally, the "git svn clone" and "git svn rebase" commands attempt to recreate empty directories that are in the Subversion repository. If this option is set to "false", then empty directories will only be created if the "git svn mkdirs" command is run explicitly. If unset, git svn assumes this option to be "true".

Note that it is easy to confuse this topic with the topic of committing/not committing empty directories to SVN (which is what `svn.rmdir` is for).

Answer (score 3):

Answer via https://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/08/17/git-svn-empty-directories/:

Modify your `~/.gitconfig` to add this as default behaviour.

```
  [svn]
  # push empty directory removals back to svn as directory deletes
  rmdir = true
```

This will make removing directories the default.